# Android app, SQLite, FTS3, create virtual table if not exists

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Beginner to SQLite/SQL. Building an Android app with FTS3 enabled, so I need to create virtual tables. I can't use this, because (according to my system log) virtual tables don't use IF NOT EXISTS syntax:

```
             // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL)',[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
            },errorHandler,successCallBack);
```

To confirm that my SQLite plug-in is working as expected, I have been using this instead:

```
            // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE User',[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
                tx.executeSql( 'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE User USING fts3 (UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL)',[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
            },errorHandler,successCallBack);
```

Which works mostly as expected (except that the `UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` no longer works, returning null every time-- suggestions for a Virtual Table friendly way to add an incrementing integer also very welcome). But I don't want to drop the table every time, I want to keep it. How can I check for the existence of the table User and only create it if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html), the correct syntax is:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User USING FTS4(...)
```

According to the [FTS documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3), you cannot explicitly declare an autoincrementing column, but every table has an implicit column called `docid` or `rowid`.